# Biztalk receive location looking at MSMQ

Tags: biztalk, msmq, biztalk-2013

I am trying to set up a receive location to pick up messages for MSMQ which have a particular label.

I have the URI correct and everything else in the BizTalk application is OK, but there are 2 things I'm unsure of and can't find any decent material to refer to:

How do I ensure BizTalk only picks the messages I'm interested in from the queue?  Surely this is not in the receive shape filter, as that would mean every message making it's way there before being evaluated?

I assume I need to code something to pick up the messages from the queue in the first place and send them to BizTalk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the MSMQ adapter in BizTalk does not allow this type of behavior. There are several other queuing technologies - like MQSC and JMS for example - which allow you to subscribe to a topic for example, but not MSMQ.

You would be best to filter messages beforehand (based on your criteria) on a separate queue for BizTalk server. With that I am assuming other messages are not supposed to be handled by BizTalk Server, but by another solution.

In case other messages would still be handled by BizTalk Server, just retrieve all messages and you can make optimal use of the publish/subscribe architecture deeply embedded in BizTalk Server.

Comment: thanks, that's what I've went for - a service to firstly separate the messages into 2 queues then Biztalk picks up from there.